# VB.net print color or black and white

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in vb.net which prints out a word document:

```
 objWordApp.PrintOut(Range:=word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintCurrentPage, _
                            Item:=word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent, _
                            Copies:="1", _
                            Pages:="1")
```

how can i add whether to print in colour or black and white?

Answer (score 0):

I think in VBA uses something like .PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = False, so if you have intellisense on your object, this might point you in the right direction.